# Some issues loading some images in keyframe slide show on IOS

Tags: css, ios, safari, slideshow, keyframe

Preload the image in the slide show then preload each additional image before the next key frame and then finally preload the original image that I started with for the final image. Even tried changing the last image to something else and it fails no error in console.

```
#slideShow{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  background-attachment: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: webkit-slideShow 30s 0.1s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moz-slideShow 30s 0.1s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: o-slideShow 30s 0.1s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: ms-slideShow 30s 0.1s linear infinite;
  animation: slideShow 30s 0.1s linear infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png");
  
  }
  @keyframes slideShow{
    0% {
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
    }
    15% {
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg")
    }
    30%{
      background-image: url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg"), url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg")
    }
    55%{
      background-image: url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
    }
    75%{
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/s2ks-127.png")
    }
    100%{
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-127.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png")
    }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes slideShow{
    0% {
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
    }
    15% {
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg")
    }
    30%{
      background-image: url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg"), url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg")
    }
    55%{
      background-image: url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
    }
    75%{
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/s2ks-127.png")
    }
    100%{
      background-image: url("../img/s2ks-127.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png")
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes webkit-slideShow{
      0% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      15% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg")
      }
      30%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg"), url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg")
      }
      55%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      75%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/s2ks-127.png")
      }
      100%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-127.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png")
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes moz-slideShow{
      0% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      15% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg")
      }
      30%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg"), url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg")
      }
      55%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      75%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/s2ks-127.png")
      }
      100%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-127.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png")
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes o-slideShow{
      0% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      15% {
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg")
      }
      30%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-60.jpeg"), url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg")
      }
      55%{
        background-image: url("../img/Jin-65.jpeg"), url("../img/s2ks-022.png")
      }
      75%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-022.png"), url("../img/s2ks-127.png")
      }
      100%{
        background-image: url("../img/s2ks-127.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png")
      }
    }
```

then in the html I have:

```
  <div id="slideShow">
header body footer etc
  </div>
```

Works fine on desktop/laptop but not in IOS safari

Comment: first i took out the extra background-size: cover; then added a second preload to the initial preload background-image:url in the #slideshow to   background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png"), url("../img/s2ks-054.png"); and that was it. now it works in ios safari

Answer (score 0):

1. I took out the extra `background-size: cover;`
2. Added a second preload to `background-image:url` in the `#slideshow` to `background-image: url("../img/s2ks-054.png");`
3. It works (on safari)
   4)had to add
   `body { background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-image: url(../img/work/4.jpg); }`

to body as well.